# Detecting font download permission in IExplorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, font-face, embedded-fonts

I am using dynamic fonts (font-face) in an HTML page.

I have seen that sometimes, IExplorer users doesn't have have permission to download fonts. This is a choice of security settings.

Is it possible to detect using Javascript if the browser allows font downloads? In this case I could display an alert or I could use an alternative technique as Cufón.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You can probe whether the desired font had been set by inspecting the computed style of text that should have the given font face.

Comment: Thanks... I have tried it using: document.getElementById('test').style.font-family but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: That's the defined style. To see what the browser actually evaluated the elements style, use `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle`.

Comment: I have tried this (and curretStyle for Explorer) but it gives me the defined style for the font-family property instead the applied one (it works fine for others properties). But... thank you, cause you've give a good track, there is another way: http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you were able to find the setting is enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 0):

This [Web Font Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) will attach [Events](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#events) to your `html tag`.

Works very good for me.